# Test if a bit is 0 or 1 x86

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

So I'm testing to see if a bit is "set" or not. bv (ebx) is my bit vector, bit (ecx) is my index 0,1,2... And return (eax) is supposed to be 0 or 1. Is there something wrong with my logic here? The c function would look like

```
int bitIsSet(unsigned int *bv, unsigned int bit)
```

Implementation in assembly:

```
#define return %eax
#define bv     %ebx
#define bit    %ecx
#define FSIZE  8

.text
.global bitIsSetBV

bitIsSetBV:
//Prologue
   subl $FSIZE, %esp  //Frame space

//Load Params
   movl FSIZE+4(%esp), %ebx  //loads *bv
   movl FSIZE+8(%esp), %ecx  //loads bit

//Func Body
   bt bit, bv               //check if 0/1
   jc END                   //if 1 jump to END
      xor return, return    //return = 0 if bv @ bit is 0
      jmp EPILOGUE          //Skip END
   END:
      movl $1, return       //return = 1 if bv @ bit is 1
//Epilogue
EPILOGUE:
   add $FSIZE, %esp  //restore stack ptr
   ret               //return = 0/1
```

I'm using GAS syntax

Comment: Your code (and therefore your question) is incomplete, because you're omitting the entry- as well as the exit code. Your question is solvable with _one OpCode_, but unless you provide the whole code, any solution will be sub-optimal.

Comment: Is it even wrong? Do you have a failing test case?

Comment: My tester is claiming it's failed.

Comment: Whatever register you're using for `return`, let's say `eax`, you can simply use the carry flag: `sbbl %eax, %eax;` (-1 if set, 0 if clear) followed by `negl %eax` (1 if set, 0 if clear), to avoid jumps. But that aside, what is actually going wrong? What are you doing with you index? It's value will always be used modulo 32.

Comment: What's your OS? Are you compiling a 32 bit or 64 bit application? It should be short enough to show the whole asm code. `bv` is passed as a pointer, so you want `bt bit, (bv)`, but without knowing the ABI, I can't be sure how your `bit` and `bv` registers are passed.

Comment: I updated it with the whole asm code. Perhaps that'll help.

Comment: If this is 32-bit ELF, `%ebx` needs to be preserved. I suggest using `%edx` in its place. You then have no need for local stack space (which you're not using anyway). Get rid of the prologue and epilogue `%esp` adjusts, and treat `FSIZE` as (0). And you need to dereference the pointer: `bt %ecx, (%edx)`.

Comment: @BrettHale That was it!